# Flex: NumericStepper rounding up decimal number

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, numericstepper

I have the following NumericStepper:

```
<s:NumericStepper id="estimertTidCell" value="{isNaN(hostComponent.estimertTid)?0:hostComponent.estimertTid}" stepSize="0.5" maximum="5" change="hostComponent.estimertTid=estimertTidCell.value"/>
```

When i set the value to e.g. 1.5 through the NumericStepper and store the value, the alert in the following code correctly displays 1.5:

```
            private var _estimertTid:Number;


        [Bindable]
        public function get estimertTid():Number {
            return _estimertTid;
        }
        public function set estimertTid(value:Number):void {
            _estimertTid = value;
            Alert.show("numeric stepper set:" + value);
            invalidateSkinState();
        }
```

**Problem:** My problem is that once the NumericStepper refreshes, or reloads the variable, it displays 2 instead of 1.5, or 4 instead of 3.5 etc. Anyone got any ideas of what is causing this behavior? I would think that by setting the stepSize=0.5 it would correctly display those decimal numbers.

**Additional information:** When i display the same variable in a spark Label, the value is correctly displayed as a decimal number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last! I found a small note that snapInterval has to be set to the same as stepSize or the value will be rounded up. So i hope my troubles help someone else in the future.
**Set snapInterval to the same as stepSze to avoid numbers rounding up**